# ORA-39244:Event to disable dropping null bit image header during relational select

Tags: oracle11g, impdp

I was trying to import a dump file using IMPDP command and has end up with the following errors:

```
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01 for user user1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 798
ORA-39244: Event to disable dropping null bit image header during relational select
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPC$QUE_INT", line 1825
ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS"
```

I have searched on oracle forums and google for any solution. Not sure why this error is happening. Is this related to the db configuration?

Comment: The issue get resolved, when I re-installed the DB.No idea why.